# Visual select from cursor to next empty line?

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block

How does one select from the current line to the next empty line?

I'm aware of <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> but then I have to either jump to the next empty line or press the down key a bunch of times.  I know how to do this well when there's a matching character like a `}` but I have no idea how to do this for an empty line.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Vim understands the concept of a "paragraph". Vim's definition of a paragraph is a block of text surrounded by blank lines<sup>*</sup>. There are several motions and text objects to work with this.

- `[count]}` – Move `[count]` paragraphs forward. You can use `<S-v>}` to select all lines from the current line to the next blank line. This will include the blank line, so you may want to use `<S-v>}k`.
- `[count]ip` – Select `[count]` paragraphs. It's like `iw` (inner word) except for, well, paragraphs. Using `vip` will select *all* of the paragraph though, rather than from the current line to the end of the paragraph.
- `[count]ap` – like `ip`, except that this will include the blank lines surrounding the paragraph.

One caveat here is that Vim *doesn't* consider a line with only whitespace as a "blank line". So make sure to check this (e.g. with `:set list`) if it doesn't appear to work.

---

Also remember you can always *search* for the pattern you want. You can get an empty line with `/^$`; or if you don't want to select the empty line itself you can use `\n\n` to put the cursor at the end of the line before the first blank line:

- `<S-v>/^$<CR>`
- `<S-v>/\n\n<CR>`

---

<sup>*</sup> There are some exceptions, see [`:help paragraph`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#paragraph) for the full logic. But for most intents and purposes this definition works fine.

Answer (score 16):

A shortcut for next empty line is <kbd>}</kbd>.
So you just might want to use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Simply pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>}</kbd> will take to next empty line without any text selection.

With <kbd>Sift</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>}</kbd>, vim selects the text from current cursor position to next empty line and you have to Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit from selection mode

Comment: Why `Shift + }`? A simple `}` does the move. See other answers.

Comment: @Ralf `Sift + }` to invoke/enter the curly bracket `}` unless your keyboard directly supports inserting `}` without pressing `Shift`